# Any ways to find another hosts in the inventory list and use it for some tasks in the playbook as value?

Tags: ansible

I am writing Ansible playbook to add the ufw firewall rules. Now the problem I am into is suppose I have 2 nodes and need to allow access between them so I am trying to add one host IP in another and vice versa. How do I achieve it?

```
[machines]
IP-ADDR-A
IP-ADDR-B
```

So to make it more clear, I would like to add the IP address of B when ansible runs playbook task for host A and vice versa.

```
- name: Allow to another nginx server
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    proto: tcp
    src: XX.XX.XX.A
    from_port: 1
    to_port: 65535
    comment: Another nginx nodes
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`|extract` filter examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/3/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) show almost your exact use case

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
     {{ groups['machines'] | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname') | list }}
```

and then you can either use the list as is, which would add an extraneous ufw allow rule for host-A, or exclude it from the list using the [`| reject` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#reject)

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
     {{ groups['machines']
     | map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname') 
     | reject('eq', inventory_hostname) 
     | list
     }}
```

Comment: `groups['machines']` is already the list of `inventory_hostname` of hosts of the group, using `map('extract', hostvars, 'inventory_hostname')` will just add extra work for the same result.